# How do I know which Columns are safe to delete because they are used by a removed content type?

Tags: 2013, list, content-type, column

This list used to have content types (A & B). We have now deleted all list items that were content type B. I have turned off Management of content types. Columns for content type B still appear in the list Settings.

**How do I know which Columns are safe to delete because they are no longer in use?**

- This list has a huge list of columns so manually checking all of them would take a long time
- This list has custom new and edit forms plus many calculated columns so comparing the forms with the list of columns would not show you all the Columns that are required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn management of content types back on. You will have a list of columns that includes "Used in." So if Column B is used in Content Type B only, it can be deleted.

[image]